# How to install snes9x from the GitHub repository?

Tags: 20.04

How I might install snes9x on Ubuntu from the GitHub repository?  https://github.com/snes9xgit/snes9x

There's no `apt-get install` command I can do.  There seem to be two possible Linux compatible version of the program (GTK or X11)

Do we have to clone the repository and compile from the source?  Is there a `*.deb` file already?

Answer (score 3):

### Binaries

There are several methods to obtain snes9x in binary form:

- Get [FlatPak version of Snes9x](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.snes9x.Snes9x) (**the easiest way**):

  1. [Install Flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu)

     ```
     sudo apt install flatpak
     flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
     ```
  2. Install Snes9x FlatPak

     ```
     flatpak install flathub com.snes9x.Snes9x
     ```
- Get snes9x from site listed on [Downloads page](http://www.snes9x.com/downloads.php) by visiting [link to *snes9x_1.60-1_amd64.deb*](https://sites.google.com/site/bearoso/snes9x/snes9x_1.60-1_amd64.deb)
- Download snes9x latest binary from [Cirrus-CI](http://cirrus-ci.com/task/6382769047601152):

  ```
  sudo apt install libportaudio2 libminizip1
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget https://api.cirrus-ci.com/v1/artifact/task/6382769047601152/build/snes9x-gtk-432fc08498b33190a41ae659c3c5fccbeb5b8b3e.txz
  tar -xf snes9x-gtk-432fc08498b33190a41ae659c3c5fccbeb5b8b3e.txz
  cd snes9x
  ./snes9x-gtk
  ```
- Get RetroArch with snes9x plugin from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=snes9x) by

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
  sudo apt-get install retroarch libretro-snes9x
  ```

  or from [libretro PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibretro/+archive/ubuntu/testing?field.series_filter=focal):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/testing
  sudo apt-get install retroarch libretro-snes9x
  ```

### From source

If you really know the reason to install from source, you can follow below method (based on [AUR PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=snes9x-git) and [snes9x Compiling wiki page](https://github.com/snes9xgit/snes9x/wiki/Compiling)):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git meson cmake \
libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libsdl2-dev glslang-dev portaudio19-dev libminizip-dev

cd ~/Downloads/
git clone https://github.com/snes9xgit/snes9x.git
cd snes9x/
git submodule update --init shaders/SPIRV-Cross
cd gtk
meson build --prefix=/usr/local --buildtype=release --strip
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

Comment: I found via Google a copy suited to version `19.04` and successfully connected all the parts.

Answer (score 1):

I had some troubles despite N0rbert very helpful answer, I list the steps that got it right (ubuntu 18.04), right after cloning from source:

```
git submodule update --init
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev libasound-dev minizip
pip3 install meson
echo "export PATH=\"`python3 -m site --user-base`/bin:$PATH\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
cd gtk && meson build --prefix=/usr/local --buildtype=release --strip
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

Two reasons:

- The version of meson installed through sudo-apt get is too low
- other submodules to update --init